# FROM missing on QueryDSL

Tags: querydsl

I'm using **QueryDSL v4.1.4** to do this query

```
.select(/*many fields*/)
.from(_product)
.join(_event).on(_product.event.eq(_event))
.join(_customer).on(_event.customer.eq(_customer))
.leftJoin(_person).on(_customer.person.eq(_person))
.leftJoin(_organization).on(_customer.organization.eq(_organization))
.where(/*many filters*/)
```

My code generate this SQL

```
SELECT --many fields
FROM product t3 
LEFT OUTER JOIN person t1 ON (t0.p_id = t1.p_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN organization t2 ON (t0.o_id = t2.o_id), 
event t4, 
customer t0
WHERE --many filters
```

But I would expect that this SQL will be generated (this SQL work fine in my DBMS)

```
SELECT --many fields
FROM product t3,
event t4, 
customer t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN person t1 ON (t0.p_id = t1.p_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN organization t2 ON (t0.o_id = t2.o_id)
WHERE --many filters
```

When trying to execute the query this exception occurs

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "t0" (customer)
```

Failed ideas to fix it

- Add all meta-models on `from` clause (this produces a useless and very heavy query)
- I'm also use `fetchJoin()` to try to force a join over other but I have the same result (exception *missing FROM-clause*)

Exist any way to force the order that a join is applied on a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are there no joins on `t3` or `t4`? I would have thought that this would result in the Cartesian product of these tables. Perhaps the joins are in the `WHERE` clause, which is not shown in the example? If so, why mix ANSI SQL and non ANSI SQL, rather than performing all the joins in the `FROM` clause? I don't think this is a querydsl issue but rather an issue with the SQL that you'd be best resolving first.

To generate the SQL requested in your question, this should do the trick. However, you should refactor your query to do ANSI style joins in the `FROM` clause and querydsl will "just work".

```
.select(/*many fields*/)
.from(_product)
.from(_event)
.from(_customer)
.leftJoin(_person).on(_customer.person.eq(_person))
.leftJoin(_organization).on(_customer.organization.eq(_organization))
.where(/*many filters*/)
```

**EDIT**

In the comments, Esvin points out there is a [varargs version](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.3/apidocs/com/querydsl/sql/ProjectableSQLQuery.html#from-com.querydsl.core.types.Expression...-) of the `from` method, so the three calls to the [standard version](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.3/apidocs/com/querydsl/sql/ProjectableSQLQuery.html#from-com.querydsl.core.types.Expression-) of the `from` method can be reduced to one: `.from(_product, _event, _customer)`

Comment: The problem is due to the order of my meta-models. Thanks @robert-bain, I just add multiple references `from(_product, _event, _customer)` the last table on `from()` method  should be the table to use on `leftJoin().on(/*here*/)` and not forgeting add where clauses to join the tables "_event" and "_customer".

Comment: Glad you got it working! I didn't see the varargs version of the `from` method. Nice!